# How to deploy a Fiori SAPUI5 application without delta mode?

Tags: deployment, sapui5, sap-fiori

I asked myself, how I can set in the configuration file (`ui5-deploy.yml`) the setting, that the application should be fully deployed instead of just the changed files:

[image: ui5-deploy.yml configuration]

So what I always see in the console during the deployment process is, that the delta mode has been activated. But I'm unsure if this is a setting, which can be overridden with the configuration file or the `fiori deploy` command in the setting.

```json
"deploy": "npm run build && fiori deploy --config ui5-deploy.yaml && rimraf archive.zip",
```

The console output says here, it has activated the delta mode:
[image: Delta mode activated in the console output]

Do you have any idea, where I could find the complete specification of the possible configuration properties or any other documentation. Note that I also found nothing inn teh schema of the `ui5.yaml.json` as defined in the `ui5-deploy.yml` file.

Answer (score 1):

So I have found another solution to this problem. I've nothing found in the docs except that we can use the flag `testMode` in the CLI options, which shows the possible changes and the files, which will be not uploaded.

Instead of searching further, you could also delete the complete `webapp/` folder of your application **except the `manifest.json`**. If you may also have changes there, you can update there a simple string or something.

Then try to upload this: It will delete all the files in the ABAP repository temporarily and therefore has later to upload all the files again. This causes that my transport request to receive again all the files which can then be later transported cleanly.

Just don't forget to reupload the webapp with your app again.

I hope this hint, may help someone who wants to deploy a refreshed version of the UI5 application but not want to use the ABAP Report (`/UI5/UI5_REPOSITORY_LOAD_HTTP`) as described here: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/topics/a560bd6ed4654fd1b338df065d331872.html